# Overriding mocked dependency for a single integration test case

Tags: c#, integration-testing, xunit

I've been following [this](https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/how-to-test-your-csharp-web-api#override-injected-instances-of-the-di-container) tutorial for writing integration tests for my project.

Doing the following I can override the DI configuration of my app using a mocked version of a dependency:

```
public class ApiWebApplicationFactory : WebApplicationFactory<Api.Startup>
{
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        // Is be called after the `ConfigureServices` from the Startup
        // which allows you to overwrite the DI with mocked instances
        builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddTransient<IWeatherForecastConfigService, WeatherForecastConfigMock>();
        });
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can override this mocked service registration for a single test case?
`services.AddTransient<IWeatherForecastConfigService, WeatherForecastConfigMock>();`

edit: attempt 1

I've added the following in my test case but it isn't overriding the default builder setup.

```
new WebApplicationFactory<Startup>().WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
            {
                builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
                {
                    var weatherForecast =
                        services.SingleOrDefault(s => s.ServiceType == typeof(IWeatherForecastConfigService));
                    services.Remove(weatherForecast);
                    services.AddScoped<IWeatherForecastConfigService, WeatherForecastConfigMockUnhappy>();
                });
            });
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Get a new factory by calling [`WebApplicationFactory<TEntryPoint>.WithWebHostBuilder(Action<IWebHostBuilder>)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.testing.webapplicationfactory-1.configurewebhost?view=aspnetcore-6.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-testing-webapplicationfactory-1-configurewebhost(microsoft-aspnetcore-hosting-iwebhostbuilder)) method on your default factory. This creates a new factory with the specified builder action and does not affect the original factory.

Comment: I've edited my original post with what i've tried. it still isn't override the default.

Comment: Excuse me but I'm not sure why you don't call `ConfigureTestServices`.

Comment: You mean instead of `builder. ConfigureServices`? I've tried it with `ConfigureTestServices` and it still doesnt fix it

Answer (score 0):

Being able to have different WebApplicationFactory mocked dependency service configurations per test is one of the main motivations for why I created a testing framework called DivertR. https://github.com/devodo/DivertR

Maybe this will help you achieve what you want to do here.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).